# language standard version versus compiler version

Tags: c, gcc, standards, versioning, c99

What is the difference between the `C` version (e.g. `C99`) and the `C` compiler version (e.g. `4.9.3`)

```
$ ./arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 4.9.3 20150529 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_9-branch revision 227977 with DYNAMIC_REENT by Ambarella]
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

How can I tell whether I am using at least C99 so that I may take advantage of certain macros.

Comment: `gcc -std=c99` asks GCC to compile your code with the C99 standard. If your compiler does not support it, you'll get an error message.  See also http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html

Comment: And according to this page C99 is fully supported since GCC 4.5: https://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C version is the name of the C standard.

Major standards in historical order:

- K&R
- ANSI (aka C89 for ANSI, and C90 for ISO)
- C99
- C11

As the C language has evolved during the last 40 years — new or amended features were introduced in those standards.

gcc compiler version - is just the version of the software. Older versions may not support newer C standards. You can inform the compiler what standard your code conforms to using command line options:

> 2.1 C Language
>
> The original ANSI C standard (X3.159-1989) was ratified in 1989 and
>   published in 1990. This standard was ratified as an ISO standard
>   (ISO/IEC 9899:1990) later in 1990. There were no technical differences
>   between these publications, although the sections of the ANSI standard
>   were renumbered and became clauses in the ISO standard. The ANSI
>   standard, but not the ISO standard, also came with a Rationale
>   document. This standard, in both its forms, is commonly known as C89,
>   or occasionally as C90, from the dates of ratification. To select this
>   standard in GCC, use one of the options `-ansi`, `-std=c90` or
>   `-std=iso9899:1990`; to obtain all the diagnostics required by the standard, you should also specify `-pedantic` (or `-pedantic-errors` if
>   you want them to be errors rather than warnings). See Options
>   Controlling C Dialect.
>
> Errors in the 1990 ISO C standard were corrected in two Technical
>   Corrigenda published in 1994 and 1996. GCC does not support the
>   uncorrected version.
>
> An amendment to the 1990 standard was published in 1995. This
>   amendment added digraphs and `__STDC_VERSION__` to the language, but
>   otherwise concerned the library. This amendment is commonly known as
>   AMD1; the amended standard is sometimes known as C94 or C95. To select
>   this standard in GCC, use the option `-std=iso9899:199409` (with, as for
>   other standard versions, `-pedantic` to receive all required
>   diagnostics).
>
> A new edition of the ISO C standard was published in 1999 as ISO/IEC
>   9899:1999, and is commonly known as C99. (While in development, drafts
>   of this standard version were referred to as C9X.) GCC has
>   substantially complete support for this standard version; see
>   http://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html for details. To select this
>   standard, use `-std=c99` or `-std=iso9899:1999`.
>
> Errors in the 1999 ISO C standard were corrected in three Technical
>   Corrigenda published in 2001, 2004 and 2007. GCC does not support the
>   uncorrected version.
>
> A fourth version of the C standard, known as C11, was published in
>   2011 as ISO/IEC 9899:2011. (While in development, drafts of this
>   standard version were referred to as C1X.) GCC has substantially
>   complete support for this standard, enabled with `-std=c11` or
>   `-std=iso9899:2011`. A version with corrections integrated is known as C17 and is supported with `-std=c17` or `-std=iso9899:2017`; the
>   corrections are also applied with `-std=c11`, and the only difference
>   between the options is the value of `__STDC_VERSION__`.
>
> By default, GCC provides some extensions to the C language that, on
>   rare occasions conflict with the C standard. See Extensions to the C
>   Language Family. Some features that are part of the C99 standard are
>   accepted as extensions in C90 mode, and some features that are part of
>   the C11 standard are accepted as extensions in C90 and C99 modes. Use
>   of the `-std` options listed above disables these extensions where they
>   conflict with the C standard version selected. You may also select an
>   extended version of the C language explicitly with `-std=gnu90` (for C90
>   with GNU extensions), `-std=gnu99` (for C99 with GNU extensions) or
>   `-std=gnu11` (for C11 with GNU extensions).
>
> The default, if no C language dialect options are given, is
>   `-std=gnu11`.
>
> The ISO C standard defines (in clause 4) two classes of conforming
>   implementation. A conforming hosted implementation supports the whole
>   standard including all the library facilities; a conforming
>   freestanding implementation is only required to provide certain
>   library facilities: those in `<float.h>`, `<limits.h>`, `<stdarg.h>`, and
>   `<stddef.h>`; since AMD1, also those in `<iso646.h>`; since C99, also
>   those in `<stdbool.h>` and `<stdint.h>`; and since C11, also those in
>   `<stdalign.h>` and `<stdnoreturn.h>`. In addition, complex types, added in
>   C99, are not required for freestanding implementations.
>
> The standard also defines two environments for programs: a
>   freestanding environment, required of all implementations and which
>   may not have library facilities beyond those required of freestanding
>   implementations, where the handling of program startup and termination
>   are implementation-defined; and a hosted environment, which is not
>   required, in which all the library facilities are provided and startup
>   is through a function `int main (void)` or `int main (int, char *[])`. An
>   OS kernel is an example of a program running in a freestanding
>   environment; a program using the facilities of an operating system is
>   an example of a program running in a hosted environment.
>
> GCC aims towards being usable as a conforming freestanding
>   implementation, or as the compiler for a conforming hosted
>   implementation. By default, it acts as the compiler for a hosted
>   implementation, defining `__STDC_HOSTED__` as 1 and presuming that when
>   the names of ISO C functions are used, they have the semantics defined
>   in the standard. To make it act as a conforming freestanding
>   implementation for a freestanding environment, use the option
>   `-ffreestanding`; it then defines `__STDC_HOSTED__` to 0 and does not make assumptions about the meanings of function names from the standard
>   library, with exceptions noted below. To build an OS kernel, you may
>   well still need to make your own arrangements for linking and startup.
>   See Options Controlling C Dialect.
>
> GCC does not provide the library facilities required only of hosted
>   implementations, nor yet all the facilities required by C99 of
>   freestanding implementations on all platforms. To use the facilities
>   of a hosted environment, you need to find them elsewhere (for example,
>   in the GNU C library). See Standard Libraries.
>
> Most of the compiler support routines used by GCC are present in
>   libgcc, but there are a few exceptions. GCC requires the freestanding
>   environment provide memcpy, memmove, memset and memcmp. Finally, if
>   `__builtin_trap` is used, and the target does not implement the trap pattern, then GCC emits a call to abort.
>
> For references to Technical Corrigenda, Rationale documents and
>   information concerning the history of C that is available online, see
>   http://gcc.gnu.org/readings.html